# Is it possible to prevent iphone view from receive touch events? If yes, How?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to prevent iphone view from receive touch events? If yes, How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
yourView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try calling

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

to tell your application to ignore touch-related events and

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

to stop ignoring touch-related events.